# Product Cipher with Two Autokey Cipher

Tags: cryptanalysis

I have a cypher text with I know encrypted two times with Autokey Cipher with same lengths of keys. I am following the statistical cryptanalysis in [here](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/stochastic-searching/cryptanalysis-autokey-cipher/) when it is ciphered with one time with Autokey and it works but I could not come up with any cryptanalysis solution when I cipher the text with Autokey cipher but two times. Anyone have any recommendation to that?